# MacBook Pro won't turns on after a water damage to the trackpad

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook Pro 13" Retina Display Early 2015 after I spilled a little water and honeslty didn't realize that it's toasted and so kept trying to turn it on. After like 48 Hours, It turned on then It kept working for few days after that trackpad stopped working. After some more days it stopped turing on. I did all that I was previously doing to turn it on like resetting PRAM, trying to boot in recovery but only SMC reset worked earlier which isn't working now. Now, When I try to reset the SMC by hitting the required keys, the charging led on the MagSafe just flicks for a bit but Macbook doesn't turn on. I opend the back panel and can confirm that the trackpad is toasted as there was little fuzziness on the track pad controller in the middle. I tried unplugging the trackpad but it didn't work either. Please let me what can I do. I am not in a position to afford major repair and I have a feeling that I can still get it working like I did last 2-3 times when it wasn't turning on and resetting SMC helped me turn it on.

Comment: The trouble with just leaving it & hoping it will get better is that it never will. What the water didn't damage initially, the corrosion will have done by now. Repair shop time. Might have been cheaper if you'd done it straight away.